# Matching 2 Separate Strings with 2 Separate Ranges to Copy the Corresponding Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to match `Date` with week number `i.e. ("B1:F1")`

[image]

then date with Year-month `i.e. ("A2:A500")`

[image]

If matches then copy the value from this table that i have highlighted according to the date which is available in code where `week is 2` and `month is May-2021`. Can someone please help me to achieve this.

There are multiple dates which i need to iterate with this table to get different values according to weeks and Year-Months.

Your help will be much appreciated.

[image]

```
Sub findMatchingRecords()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim getdate As String
Dim GetWeek As String
        
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
getdate = ws.Range("N1").Value
GetWeek = Int((Day(getdate) + 6) / 7)

Set rng1 = ws.Range("B1:F1")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("A2:A500")

For Each rng1cell In rng1
    For Each rng2cell In rng2

        If rng1cell = GetWeek And rng2cell = Format(getdate, "yyyy-mmm") Then

            'Copy value and paste into Sheet1.Range("M2")

        End If

    Next rng1cell
Next rng2cell

End Sub
```

Here are the dates which needs to match with table and get relevant the value.

```
5/13/2021
5/16/2021
5/19/2021
5/22/2021
5/25/2021
5/28/2021
5/31/2021
6/3/2021
6/6/2021
6/9/2021
6/12/2021
6/15/2021
6/18/2021
6/21/2021
6/24/2021
```

Comment: Is the month column actually stored as dates or is it just "2021-May"?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If you take date + 1, what happens? Does it give number or error?

Comment: No it does not stored as date it is just value `"2021-May"` My mistake not to understand the question yes it will give error.

Comment: Okay, so it's a String then? You can likely avoid VBA entirely if so.

Comment: Actually the problem is there are multiple dates in other file and this table is on different file thats why asked for VBA. But how to achieve excluding VBA.

Comment: Oh so the other table will have duplicates?

Comment: Yes there will be different dates where week and month will change accordigly.

Comment: I recommend you edit your question in order to accommodate the scope of the initial question changing, as this this effects the solution you need. In your image, include a few duplicate examples, or at least mention they'll be there and note what the expected result should be in these circumstances (sum, avg, etc.). Mention the data type of the dates, for example if it's just a string mention that, again this changes the solution needed.

Comment: I looked to your code, I read, at least I tried reading carefully your question, but I did not understand what your pictures represent, against the story behind your words... So, should the code iterate between the last picture column cells? What range does it represent it in your code? Or, in whatever place... Is it situated in  N:N column? What sheet does it belong to? Then, does your first two pictures make part from the third one? If so, do you need to return near the column in the last picture, all matches in the third picture?

Comment: Are there two sheets involved? If yes, which is which, in terms of ranges to be processed?

Comment: thank you so much @FaneDuru for look into my question. Yes code should iterate on last picture. Right Now i am just trying to get the value for single date that is available in Sheet1 and whenever date will change its week, month and year will change accordingly. Below Answered formula works perfect but i cannot use the formula.

Comment: No there are no two sheet I used same sheet that is Sheet1.

Comment: You did not say where the code to return what you need. If the column having dates is N:N, should the code return in O:O? Then, are there only these 5 week numbers, or you show only part of your sheet?

Comment: yes Code can return in O:O Yes there are only five weeks for each month there cannot be 6 week.

Comment: So they are the weeks **of the month** not the year weeks, as I initially thought...

Comment: Apologize that i cannot write it well. Yes you are right

Comment: Does 2021-Nov is missing on purpose, or it should be there, too?

Comment: No there is no purpose table has approx. 200 values like `2021-Nov` , `2022-Oct` etc where it can be   different

Comment: So, does the range to be processed contain more than the visible cells (12 rows) we can see? At least, the strings in the first column are them unique?

Comment: Yes its more than visible rows. Yes they all are unique. Col A has unique values

Comment: OK. I will try preparing an answer. Not time right now, but if nobody else will post one, I will do it...

Comment: I hope you will post an answer Thank you for sparing the time reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Non-VBA Method

One way this could be done without using VBA is with a `INDEX/MATCH` formula.

The following formula assumes the data is in `B2:F500`, the month/years are in `A2:A500`, the weeks in B1:F1 and the dates to look for are in column `N`, all on the same sheet `Sheet1`.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$F$13,MATCH(TEXT(N1,"yyyy-mmm"),Sheet1!$A$2:$A$13,0),MATCH(INT((DAY(N1)+6)/7),Sheet1!$B$1:$F$1,0))
```

### VBA Method

If you want VBA to do this here's one way.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub findMatchingRecords()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngDates As Range
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim arrDates As Variant
Dim arrYearMonth As Variant
Dim arrValues As Variant
Dim arrWeeks As Variant
Dim Res As Variant
Dim idxCol As Long
Dim idxDate As Long
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim wk As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Set rngData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rngDates = .Range("N1", .Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With rngData
        arrData = rngData.Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1)
        arrYearMonth = .Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
        arrWeeks = .Rows(1).Offset(, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1)
    End With

    arrDates = rngDates.Value

    ReDim arrValues(1 To UBound(arrDates, 1), 1 To 1)

    For idxDate = LBound(arrDates, 1) To UBound(arrDates, 1)
        idxRow = 0
        idxCol = 0
        Res = Application.Match(Format(arrDates(idxDate, 1), "yyyy-mmm"), arrYearMonth, 0)
        If Not IsError(Res) Then
            idxRow = Res
            wk = Int((Day(arrDates(idxDate, 1)) + 6) / 7)
            Res = Application.Match(wk, arrWeeks, 0)
            If Not IsError(Res) Then
                idxCol = Res
            End If
        End If

        If idxRow <> 0 And idxCol <> 0 Then
            arrValues(idxDate, 1) = arrData(idxRow, idxCol)
        End If
    Next idxDate

    rngDates.Offset(, 1).Value = arrValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you i know that Index Match can do this but i need to done it through VBA.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include code to do the matching.

Comment: is there a way to convert this line to `Set rngData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion` into this `Lrow = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))' 
        'Set rngData = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)`  I did it but having an error @norie on line `Lrow` Typr Mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub MatchDate_WeekNo()
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrN, arrfin, i As Long, strDate As String
Dim weekN As Long, arrRow, arrCol, iCol As Variant, iRow As Variant, lastRN As Long

Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRN = sh.Range("N" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
arr = sh.Range("A1:F" & lastR).Value
 arrRow = Application.Index(arr, 1, 0)

 arrCol = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 0, 1))
arrN = sh.Range("N2:N" & lastRN).Value2
ReDim arrfin(1 To UBound(arrN), 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To UBound(arrN)
    strDate = StringFromDate(CDate(arrN(i, 1)))
    weekN = Int((Day(arrN(i, 1)) + 6) / 7)
    iCol = Application.Match(weekN, arrRow, 0)
    iRow = Application.Match(strDate, arrCol, 0)
    If IsNumeric(iCol) And IsNumeric(iRow) Then
        arrfin(i, 1) = arr(iRow, iCol)
    End If
Next i
'drop the final array content:
sh.Range("O2").Resize(UBound(arrfin), 1).Value = arrfin
End Sub

Function StringFromDate(d As Date) As String
Dim arrM
 Const strMonths As String = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec"
 arrM = Split(strMonths, ",")
   StringFromDate = Year(d) & "-" & Application.Index(arrM, Month(d))
End Function
```

`Format(arrDates(idxDate, 1), "yyyy-mmm")` does not return the month in case of localization different then English type and only that's why I am using a function...

Comment: Thank you very much but an error is appear on the line `iCol = Application.Match(weekN, arrRow, 0)` that is `Type Mismatch`

Comment: @Valiant  When stopped on error and moving the cursor over `strDate` what does it show?

Comment: This value is appear on strDate  `2021-May`

Comment: OK. Please insert this code line on top of the one raising the error. What does it return in Immediate Window? Something like "Months|2021-Jan|2021-Feb|2021-Mar|....."? Are your strings like "2021-May" in column A:A? If not, in which column does it exist? In such a case `arrCol` should be using that column number... And something else: Is the row containing the week number the first, or the second? My code  considers it being the second... I thought it maybe some headers exists.

Comment: Which code line ? Yes there is string "2021-May" in column A:A

Comment: Ups... I forgot to post he code line... Next one: `Debug.Print Join(arrCol, "|"): Stop`. In fact, I wrote it but probably selected by mistake and wrote something else over it. To be on top of the line raising the error. Now when I am rewrite it I am sure I did it, but nevermind...

Comment: Yes the same answer is appearing in the immediate window as you said. How i can mind even you are helping me. I just can appreciate the help.

Comment: Then, no sense to raise such an error. If the string is the correct one, the array the same, it should work. I tested the code on some sample data... You already have a working answer, but if you will share the workbook in discussion I will tell you where the problem is. Otherwise, I simple cannot understand why. Theoretically, it should work as in my computer. You said that 2021-May is a string. Isn't it correct?

Comment: There are two issues: 1. The row keeping the week numbers is the first. Like I said, my code processes a range starting from the second row. I supposed that there is a headers row. Your picture does not show rows and columns headers. Then, I understood that the N:N column has the same number of data like A:A and when set the array I used the same `lastR`. I will adapt the above code and I will also send the processed workbook in a minute...

Comment: @Valiant Adapted the code. Please, download the processed workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/7vuw2r).

Comment: Thank you very very much its working now.

Comment: When i expanded the dates to 50+ rows it gives the values for those dates which year-months are not available in the table.

Comment: @Valiant So, is it possible a correspondence to not exist? If so, you should state it. Not complicated to adapt the code, but not knowing anything about the aspect, I did not even try to catch such situations. What should be returned in such a situation? Shell the code skip that specific case and nothing to be returned?

Comment: Yes it is possible to exist sorry to bothering you. i tried added on error resume next but still added those values. Yes it should skip

Comment: @Valiant Please, try the updated code. Basically I changed declarations of `iCol` and `iRow` in `Variant` (to also accept error messages) and conditioned placing the result in the final array only if both of them are numbers...